# "Presented today with" vs "presented herself today with"?

Tags: word-usage

Context: Hospital setting – Referral Letter

1. She presented today with symptoms of COPD.
2. She presented **herself** today with symptoms of COPD.

In both cases, *to the hospital* is omitted. Are both correct? The first sentence somehow doesn't ring right.

Comment: Don't you mean "doesn't ring true"? "Doesn't ring right" rings no bells for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is common in medicine, either in practice or in medical literature, to talk of a patient presenting (intransitive).

For example: "The patient presented with interstitial oedematous pancreatitis."

> **To present:** To appear for examination or treatment, said of a patient.
>
> [[Farlex Partner Medical Dictionary]](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/present)

A letter of referral from the diagnosing doctor to the hospital doctors would therefore normally say "She presented today with symptoms of COPD". The inclusion of "*herself*" is redundant in this usage.

The full context of the letter is not clear from your question but I assume it to be from a diagnosing doctor (either in the hospital or in general practice) to a hospital doctor. In either case "*to the hospital*" or "*at the hospital*" is not needed because the context is entirely clear. Nor is the phrase needed as a qualifier to "she presented".

Comment: Sorry but I noticed nothing. Your edits are usually pretty good so please do it again if you can :)

Comment: Thank you for that.

Comment: Thanks Anton! Grew up used to using the `redundant' rule, perhaps!

Comment: @VinooRobert Gracious of you. Thanks :)